# Is there a generic way to run development tests for Debian packages?

Tags: testing, debian, apt-get, dpkg

On Debian, one can download the source of packages using

```
apt-get source <package>
```

The source can be built with

```
cd <package>-*; dpkg-buildpackage -uc -b
```

Is there a similarly generic way to run the development tests for the packages?

Answer (score 5):

running tests is actually handled by the package itself, that is `debian/rules`.

packages that have this enabled will automatically run the test-suite during the build (`dpkg-buildpackage`), and the build-process will fail if the test-suite fails.

from the packager's side a way to automate this, is to use `dh`, which will run `dh_auto_test` which in turn will try try to run the "usual suspects", e.g. `make check` (or `make test`).

if the package in question does not automatically run the test-suite and you don't want to modify the `debian/rules`, and your package is reasonable simple, you could simply run

```
 make check
```

yourself after a successfull build, as `dpkg-buildpackage` usually will not cleanup after the build. obviously this will only work if the way to run the test is by executing `make check`